# Channel permissionOverwrites

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

For some reason whenever I assign permission overwrites for @everyone when making a channel it doesn't actually do the overwrites I select.

```
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return
    if (interaction.customId === 'ticketcreate') 
            {
                
                const ticketCreation = await interaction.guild.channels.create(interaction.user.username + ' ticket', { //Create ticket channel
                    type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
                    permissionOverwrites: [
                        {
                            id: interaction.user.id,
                            allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY", "SEND_MESSAGES"]
                        },
                        {
                            id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
                            deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY"]
                        }
                    ],
                })
```

So this should make everyone in the guild  not be able to view the channel or read message history and make the person that interacted with the button view the channel and read message history. However it doesn't do this. (this button creates a support ticket and I don't want everyone to be able to see the support ticket for obvious reasons)

Comment: I've checked your code and it works fine for me. So, does your bot create the channel but if you check the permissions on discord's permissions tab, you can't see these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're passing in strings for the permissions...I believe the docs say this should be bitfield flags...here's the specs:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create

and the example listed shows the code example too:

```
deny: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL],
```

info from discordjs on Permissions:
https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#terminology

scroll down to Base permissions
#Setting role permissions

````
guild.channels.create('new-channel', {
    type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
    permissionOverwrites: [
        {
            id: message.guild.id,
            deny: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL],
        },
        {
            id: message.author.id,
            allow: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL],
        },
    ],
});```
````

Comment: This still isn't working for me for some reason

Comment: comma delimited should work.  note you have a typo using a , after Permissions on the first one.

Comment: giving me this issue now when trying to run
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')

Comment: I'll add more helpful links for you in my answer

Comment: No longer have the above error but it still doesn't work. Doesn't actually set those as the channel perms and I have this

                    permissionOverwrites: [
                        {
                            id: interaction.user.id,
                            deny: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL],
                        },
                        {
                            id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
                            deny: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL]
                        }
                    ],
                })

Comment: post your code, if it's still not working...I'm amending with the specific code block from the example sites I posted, that shows the array of objects style...ensure you have that.  Not sure what else you want here, but you don't like my answer, even though it's all there.  edit your original post with your code if you want any more help.

Comment: This is incorrect. You don't have to use flags, you can use strings as OP did. If you check the [`PermissionResolvable`s documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/typedef/PermissionResolvable), it mentions that it can be a string, a permission number, an instance of `Permission`s, or an array of `PermissionResolvable`s